# How can a very simple /alive rest api nodejs expressjs time out?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

On a nodejs/expressjs server running on Heroku, I have some API.
90% of the 45req/s (max)  are to a simple `/alive` api that only returns http 200.

```
app.get('/alive', (req, res) => res.status(200).json('OK'));
```

But sometimes ... all `/alive` calls repond with HTTP 503 and 30s timeout ...
even after rebooting my server...
But 2 hours later ... it goes well again ...

dyno load stays low, memory keeps growing very very slowly. 1 to 10 dyno change nothing.

NewRelic says that all the time is used by

> Expressjs: GET /alive

Is it possible that an API call blocks all other calls? and how can I detect it?